# InStr vs indexOf

Tags: javascript, function, vbscript, indexof, instr

Is this ASP InStr function equivalent to the js indexOf function :

ASP :

```
<%
Function validation(ByVal var2)
  If (InStr(var1, "," & var2 & ".") = 0) Then
    validation = 1
    Exit Function
  End If
End Function
%>
```

JS :

```
validation = function(var2) {
  if (var1.indexOf("," + var2 + ".") == -1) {
      ValidateAction = 1;
  };
  return ValidateAction;
};
```

Comment: If you are only interested in checking if `var2` (with `,` before and `.` after) exists within `var1`, then they are equivalent, yes.

Comment: OP problem solved !

Answer (score 4):

No, they are same only with one case. If value not found InStr return 0 and indexOf return -1, but Instr has many other, have a look on

**Differences**

The InStr function returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

The InStr function can return the following values:

```
If string1 is "" - InStr returns 0
If string1 is Null - InStr returns Null
If string2 is "" - InStr returns start
If string2 is Null - InStr returns Null
If string2 is not found - InStr returns 0
If string2 is found within string1 - InStr returns the position at which match is found
If start > Len(string1) - InStr returns 0
```

Whereas javascript `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

```
This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.
```